# Unpickling a log file(Decoding)

Tags: encoding, decoding

I have been trying to unpickle it or at least decode it  but I don't understand how to do and I need help! I don't know python but I am trying to learn! And can someone tell me what the encoding is?[This is the file and also the info is in the log, I think](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkbvzv9ys59urnu/quick-4-LT1.save?dl=0)

Comment: Can you say how do you got this file? Some code could give us clues about that.

Comment: I went through the files using 7 zip C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Scheherazade\game\saves\quick-4-LT1.save\